# Catch simple arithmetic progression with spiral bijection

Tags: arithmetic-progression

Consider the simple arithmetic progression ($s, z \in \mathbb{Z}$):

$a_1 = s$

$a_{n+1} = a_n + z = s + n\cdot z$

Can somebody devise a procedure (another progression) $b_n$ so that there exists a $m\in \mathbb{N}$ with $b_m = a_m$?

One simple approach is to spiral out from zero (spiral bijection) in $Z^2$:

$b_1 = 0 + 0$

$b_2 = 0 + 1$

$b_3 = 1 + 1$

$b_4 = 1 + 0$

$b_5 = 1 -1$

$...$

But it seems that you never have a guarantee that the arithmetic progression is too fast to catch.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Relevant tweet from Kelsey Houston-Edwards: https://twitter.com/KelseyAHE/status/997502388008312834.

Comment: It seems to me that you want more than what you asked. What you want, as in Kelsey's problem, is a sequence $b_n$ such that $\forall s\forall z$ there is $m$ with $b_m=a_m$, where $a_n=s+n\cdot z$. That is, you want one spiral sequence that hits all the arithmetic progressions. Otherwise, to hit just one progression, take $b_1=a_1$ and you're done, which is clearly not what you want.

Comment: Youre right. s,z is fixed but random. But is there such a progression that hits all such arithmetic Progressions? The spiral seems to be to slow.

Comment: There's a countable infinity of arithmetic progressions, right? So why not just list them, $P_1,P_2,P_3,\dots,$ and let $b_m$ be the $m$th term of the progression $P_m$? Ah, now I've looked at the tweet, this is just what Joel wrote. Never mind.

Comment: Thanks for your input! You only look at the mth term of the progression P_m. That's the trick / solution. Thanks Gerry.